# Java object size using Instrumentation: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing when running agent jar

Tags: java, object, jar, javac, instrumentation

I was referring [one article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object) to get the size of my object. After completing all the steps I got stuck in running that .jar file:

Before that, I ran:

```
mvn package
```

My VM Argument is:

`-javaagent: "C:\Users\user1\workspace\Test\target\Test.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"`

and

`-javaagent: C:\Users\user1\workspace\Test\target\Test.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

In both the cases I am getting below errors:

```
error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init:instrument
error opening zip file or jar manifest missing :
```

IDE

```
Eclipse : Oxygen.3a Release
```

Just for reference my main class is:

```
public MyClass{

public static void printObjectSize(Object obj){
        System.out.println(IntrumentationAgent.getObjectSize(object));
}

public static void main (String args ..) throws..{
        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        printObjectSize(myClass )
    }
}
```

MANIFEST.MF file:

```
1.Premain-class: com.test.InstrumentAgent
2.
```

Comment: No space after the colon: `-javaagent:path` or `"-javaagent:path"`.

Comment: After changing I am getting another error - "class not found exception: InstrumentAgent. FATAL ERROR in vative method: processing of -javaagent failed"

Comment: Make sure that the class exists in the jar file and its path within the archive matches its package. The article you've linked looks sloppy in that regard.